# Remove all words after a specific word from a column

Tags: r, string, data-cleaning

I'm looking to remove all words and characters that appear after specific words (including that word) in a column.

This is what my data looks like.

|  | Number.of.Workers | company_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5195 | 82 | valley ho hotels aka kings inn |
| 5196 | 82 | aluminum precision products |
| 5197 | 79 | levity of brea dba brea improv |
| 5198 | 79 | crunch |
| 5199 | 71 | comedy club of los angeles dba hollywood improv |
| 5200 | 65 | andre-boudin bakeries inc dba boudin |

A specific example what I like to accomplish is that I like to remove any word after "aka" and "dba" and the words "aka" and "dba" from my data.

```
structure(list(Number.of.Workers = c("82", "82", "79", "79", 
"71", "65", "62", "58", "56", "53", "49"), company_name = c("valley ho hotels aka kings inn", 
"aluminum precision products", "levity of brea  dba brea improv", 
"crunch", "comedy club of los angeles  dba hollywood improv", 
"andre-boudin bakeries inc   dba boudin", "comedy club of san jose  dba san jose improv", 
"comedy club of brea  dba ontario improv", "sprout bost ", "culver west lp - playa provisions", 
"faa concord h dba concord honda")), row.names = 5195:5205, class = "data.frame")
```

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sub()` as follows:

```
df$company_name = sub("\\s+(aka|dba|\\(formerly.*[)])\\s+.*$", "", df$company_name)
```

output:

```
     Number.of.Workers                      company_name
5195                82                  valley ho hotels
5196                82       aluminum precision products
5197                79                    levity of brea
5198                79                            crunch
5199                71        comedy club of los angeles
5200                65         andre-boudin bakeries inc
5201                62           comedy club of san jose
5202                58               comedy club of brea
5203                56                      sprout bost 
5204                53 culver west lp - playa provisions
5205                49                     faa concord h
```

Note: thanks to @Chris Ruehlemann for pointing out `sub` vs `gsub`. The difference is that the former replaces the first occurrence, while the latter replaces all.

Comment: Thank you! Could I also add a character before something I want to remove? for example if something has (formerly know as ...) can I put the "(formerly" part in the above code?

Comment: `gsub` is not needed, `sub` will do

Comment: I'm not surewhat you mean @bear_525. The general answer is yes - but perhaps give a specific example.. or ask a separate question that shows the example.

Comment: for example if the company_name column has a company as follows: "company x (formerly know as some other company)" can I put the "(formerly" part in the above code? In other words is the parenthesis allowed in the code?

Comment: sure, as above.

Answer (score 3):

In Base R:

```
#remove any word after "aka" and "dba" 
df$company_name <- gsub("(aka|dba).*", "", df$company_name)

#remove the words "aka" and "dba" 
df$company_name <- gsub("(\\s*aka\\s*|\\s*dba\\s*)", "", df$company_name)
```

```
     Number.of.Workers                      company_name
5195                82                 valley ho hotels 
5196                82       aluminum precision products
5197                79                  levity of brea  
5198                79                            crunch
5199                71      comedy club of los angeles  
5200                65      andre-boudin bakeries inc   
5201                62         comedy club of san jose  
5202                58             comedy club of brea  
5203                56                      sprout bost 
5204                53 culver west lp - playa provisions
5205                49                    faa concord h
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(df$company_name, "\\s+(aka|dba).*$")
 [1] "valley ho hotels"                  "aluminum precision products"       "levity of brea"                    "crunch"                            "comedy club of los angeles"       
 [6] "andre-boudin bakeries inc"         "comedy club of san jose"           "comedy club of brea"               "sprout bost "                      "culver west lp - playa provisions"
[11] "faa concord h"
```

**EDIT**:

If the choice of strings from which to start removing is this:

**either** `aka` **or** `dba` **or** `(formerly known as x)` (where `x` is a placeholder for a company name)

then you will need alternation between two patterns:

```
x <- c("valley ho hotels aka kings inn", 
        "aluminum precision products", 
        "levity of brea  (formerly known as brea improv)", 
        "crunch", 
        "comedy club of los angeles  dba hollywood improv")

str_remove(x, "\\s+(aka|dba).*$|\\s+\\(formerly[^)(]+\\)")
[1] "valley ho hotels" "aluminum precision products" "levity of brea" "crunch" "comedy club of los angeles"
```

Comment: Thank you! Could I also add a character before something I want to remove? for example if the company_name column has a company as follows: "company x (formerly know as some other company) can I put the "(formerly" part in the above code? In other words is the parenthesis allowed in the code?

Comment: You mean **either** `aka` **or** `dba` **or** `(formerly known as x)`?

Comment: Yes, to remove "aka", "dba", "(formerly" . I assume I only need to use the first part of (formerly known as x) because what ever comes after formerly will be removed. This will work better for me because the sentence structure can change over my dataset. but the word formerly always stays the same.